# Varibles Initialized in Awake are null in other script's Start

Tags: unity, c#

I have a component gameState Attached to one gameobject called GameState:

```
public class gameState : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Context stateMachine;
        private void Awake()
        {
            PlayerGameobject p = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerGameobject>();
            stateMachine = new Context(new Playing(), p); 
        }
```

On another gameObject I have this component:

```
public class PlayerGameobject : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {

        gameState = GameObject.Find("GameState").GetComponent<gameState>();
    }

}
```

When I try to use gameState within PlayerGameobject's Update method I find that stateMachine is null.

```
 if (gameState.stateMachine.CurrentState == "Playing"){}
      //       ^^^^ null
```

why is statemachine null? I initialized it in awake which should run before start. gameState is not null and other public variables assigned in Editor are not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided code won't work properly since you name your class `gameState` and access `gameState.stateMachine` while `stateMachine` is not static. Make sure you access the `stateMachine` of the GameState instance.

Another guess: it might be possible that the `new Context(...)` in your gameState Awake causes an exception which leads to `stateMachine` being `null`. You would directly spot that in the console though.

Comment: The error was inside new Context, Hidden among the spam of errors the update method was giving. Turns out that unity will abort the Awake method if it come across a nullReference error.

Comment: That *aborting* is really a thrown Exception. Exceptions are *thrown upwards* unless you catch them with a `try-catch` block.